# How can I disable ads on my app after a user has clicked say more than five times?

Tags: admob, ads

Disable ads after some clicks by a user  How to code this in android studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply you can use count variable in (say) onAdClick() method and put condition in it like,

```
`onAdclick(){
count++;
if(count>5)
disableAd();
}`
```

Comment: Thanks bro ,I'm a noob can you tell me where to paste this .

Comment: I have just used an Example, Its not the required code.

Comment: This link might be helpfull. https://www.androidhive.info/2016/02/android-how-to-integrate-google-admob-in-your-app    you can use count variable in onClick(View view) in MainActivity.java as it is opening the ads in as SecondActivity. If you want exact answer show me the code.

Answer (score 1):

These code will help you.

**build.gradle**

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.2.0'
```

**MainActivity Codes**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

AdView mAdView;
int click = 0;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
boolean timeUp = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    BannerAdsLoad(); // Here I'm calling a method to load ads.

    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Ads", MODE_PRIVATE);

}

private void BannerAdsLoad() {
    MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
        }
    });
    mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            // Code to be executed when an ad finishes loading.
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(LoadAdError adError) {
            // Code to be executed when an ad request fails.
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdOpened() {
       
          // here i'm sharing total clicks on ads & last click time 
            click++;
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putInt("Click", click);
            String date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());
            editor.putString("blockDate", date);
            editor.apply();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClicked() {
            // Code to be executed when the user clicks on an ad.

        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            // Code to be executed when the user is about to return
            // to the app after tapping on an ad.
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (!timeUp)
        blockUserDialog(); // Block User Dialog, You can customize it 
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    String currDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());
    SharedPreferences sfr = getSharedPreferences("Ads", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String blockDate = sfr.getString("blockDate", currDate);
    try {
        Date date1 = simpleDateFormat.parse(currDate);
        Date date2 = simpleDateFormat.parse(blockDate);
        long diff = (date1.getTime() - date2.getTime()) / (1000 * 60) % 60;
        if (!(diff == 2 || diff > 2)) {
            blockUserDialog();
        }
        timeUp = true;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private void blockUserDialog() {

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Ads", MODE_PRIVATE);
    int clicks = sharedPreferences.getInt("Click", 0);
    if (clicks == 3) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).
                setTitle("You are blocked due to more clicks on ad for 2 Minutes")
                .setPositiveButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finish();
                    }
                }).setCancelable(false).show();
    }
}
```

}